# Using a constant-length 2D array as a struct member in C

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to do the following in C:

- create a 2d array (with compile-time known dimensions) of integers on the stack
- assign the array as a member of a struct (which used in a callback function elsewhere)

I tried using a struct either with a 2d array member or pointer to 2d array - see code below.

I could probably just use a double pointer allocated with malloc and have a double pointer struct member, but I was trying to avoid dynamic allocation (and I'd like to understand what is going wrong). I also don't want to copy the array because the callback function might mutate the data.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct numbers_struct {
    int numbers[2][3];
};

struct pointer_to_numbers_struct {
    int (*numbers)[2][3];
}

int main() {
    int numbers[2][3] = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6} };

    /* try to use struct with 2d array member
     * error: array type `int[2][3]` not assignable */
    struct numbers_struct num_struct;
    num_struct.numbers = numbers;

    /* try to use struct with pointer to 2d array member 
     * contains random/invalid data */
    struct pointer_to_numbers_struct ptr_num_struct;
    ptr_num_struct.numbers = &numbers;
}
```

Comment: The first assignment fails because arrays aren't actually pointers, you can't assign an array to something, to pull off the first one you're gonna need to copy element by element.
as for the second one, keep in mind ```num_struct.numbers``` is a **pointer** to a 2d array, to actually access the elements you have to deference it to get the array and then you can index it through it normally.

Comment: You cannot copy arrays by assignment, but you can copy `struct` types by assignment. So if you had `struct numbers_struct nums = { { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}};` and `struct numbers_struct num_struct;` you could assign `num_struct = nums;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign an array like that, try memcpy instead:

```
memcpy(num_struct.numbers, numbers, sizeof numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the arrays within the initializer of `struct numbers_struct`.

```
struct numbers_struct num_struct = { { {1,2,3},{4,5,6} } };
struct pointer_to_numbers_struct ptr_num_struct = { &num_struct.numbers };
```

If you want the structure to be persistent, add `static` to its definition.